# Lotus Domino Group Account Concern

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Currently, we do have lotus administration as our email server.
We have multiple user and group accounts. I say AllEmail is a group account that are members of user1, user2 and user3. The default or primary function of AllEmail group is that when you send here on this email all members will be also sent a copy of the email.

How about only defined users can used the group account? Even so all the users are members of this group account.

Hoping for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common question. I invite you to read: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_RESTRICTING_MAIL_TO_PUBLIC_GROUP_STEPS.html

Comment: Wow mate, thanks. But i do have a concern, does it takes effect immediately?..i've tried to refresh policy using tell adminp pa m

Comment: It's based on $Readers Field, change should be immediate. You can also make a shift+ctrl+F9 in any view of the names (could be heavy for large NAB)

Comment: It almost work sir, the user who do not have access was denied. but when a user which is a member of that group and send to that group not sending properly. it messages you have outgoing mails when prompt on exiting the notes program.

Comment: please check that for this user, the pending mail is the one sent to the group. The other users can send to the restricted group (properly)?

Comment: Group1 is member of user1 and user2. But user1 has read access to Group1. user2 when using the group1 is denied which is correct. But when user1 sends to the group1 it does send but does not receive. i no longer receive the pending messages for sending.

Comment: i would like to clarify sir, i am the user and member of that group. i send an email on that group but i am the only one who did not receive the email even though i am a member of the group. is this normal? since the creator of email will not receive his sent items..

Comment: that i do believe, thank you sir! very helpful and link provided. can you help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25488243?noredirect=1 :)