# Lotus Domino Create Standard Location / Signature

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Is this possible for my request? I would like to create a un-changaeable or definite (locations and signature) for each user on Lotus Domino..if possible on server-side, I do believe the only was creating a template for each user. Is there a possible way a template but dynamically changes on user logon so that his/her signature will vary also.

Thanks guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at a 3rd party tool, for exampel Crossware Mail Signature.
If I understand it correctly when talking to them (we are looking for a server-based signature system as well), you can set it up so that the signatures are different for diferent users or department, as well as for internal vs external email.

Comment: Do we have no alternative option? Still great information sir